# Accounts can't connect to the users in my mongo DB user collections

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts, simple-schema

I'm building a custom account system with meteor accounts package when i register a new user accounts is loggin him directly (a behavior that i does'nt asked) and *meteor toys shows one user in collection (despite the others that i have added previously)* **this is because i didn't publish users**. When i'm creating a new user with existing username it returns an error but also redirect and the user is logged in please i need help with this

```
// Meteor server side method for register
Meteor.methods({
    'users.register'( data ) {
        try {
            user = Accounts.createUser({
                username: data.username,
                password: data.password,
            });
            return {
                "userId": user
            };
        } catch (e) {
            throw e;
        }
    },
});
// register call on register.js (client side register page)
Meteor.call('users.register', registerable, ( error ) => {
     if( error ){
         if( error.error == 403 ){
             usernameExistMessage.style.display = "inline";
         } else {
             usernameExistMessage.style.display = "none";
         }
      }
});

// Users in the mongo collection
{ "_id" : "7re7XPXoxrs6oYckN", "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-18T16:51:31.742Z"), "services" : { "password" : { "bcrypt" : "$2a$10$8NZwd1gPMpJgMs8P47DF.uHWrvBLilTBcp6D0q6877HcDJOfJKaz6" }, "resume" : { "loginTokens" : [ ] } }, "username" : "test" }
{ "_id" : "96rc3NYXr35HNB6uZ", "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-01-18T16:52:07.421Z"), "services" : { "password" : { "bcrypt" : "$2a$10$Y3Bb6B/o3MwnFevNGpqtROMcH833qtHF.OEx6Qg5xbJrwXRU2u.2q" }, "resume" : { "loginTokens" : [ ] } }, "username" : "username" }
```

[image: Meteor toys showing o users in the user collection]

User auto logged in after creation of a new account even if the user already exist in mongo user collection

[image: User auto loggedIn after register]

My meteor package file

```
meteor-base@1.4.0             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience@1.0.5       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo@1.6.0                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates@1.0.4 # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
reactive-var@1.0.11            # Reactive variable for tracker
tracker@1.2.0                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifier-css@1.5.2   # CSS minifier run for production mode
standard-minifier-js@2.4.0    # JS minifier run for production mode
es5-shim@4.8.0                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers
ecmascript@0.12.4              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code
shell-server@0.4.0            # Server-side component of the `meteor shell` command

accounts-password
kadira:flow-router
kadira:blaze-layout

fastclick
less@2.8.0                    # Leaner CSS language
aldeed:simple-schema
aldeed:collection2
alanning:roles

meteortoys:allthings
```

Comment: The issue you described involved at least three different points of possible failure. Please try to narrow down the scope and explain how the code you posted is related to the issue. Edit: this means also to add the error stack to your question and the code you have used to create a user.

Comment: roger @Jankapunkt

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue there was some wrong imports and a template events bad handling